# Time it takes IOS to delete an application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if there is anything a programmer can do to speed up the time it takes IOS to delete the app. I am actually referring to the time it takes from pressing the "x" delete button and the time the dialogue appears. My guess is, this is when the OS does some calculations on the file sizes of the app and the total number files stored in the app bundle might influence the delete process, but I want to be sure this is the case. I couldn't find any reference on that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess is, this is when the OS does some calculations on the file sizes of the app and the total number files stored in the app bundle might influence the delete process

There is a simple test you can make to verify that whether this hypothesis is correct.

1. Long press on an app icon; when the "x" appears, tap on it; wait until the dialog appears;
2. go to another app and do the same;
3. go to another app and do the same;
4. ...

To make the test more "cogent" you could choose an app at step 2/3/... that you know stores many files locally and has a large number of files.

In my case, I have seen that the first time it takes a noticeable time for the dialog to appear; successively, the dialog will appear almost immediately.

So, I do not think it depends, on the app; rather on the state of the device, the need to release some memory, load some code, etc... Once done, this is fast, until released once again.

So, sadly, I don't think there is anything a developer can do to reduce the time between tapping on the "x" and the appearance of the dialog.

Comment: tested again and I think you are correct. I was checking wrong, always my app first and then others. Thanks for the effort!